# Making big samples with Park&Miller RNGs?

Tags: c, pointers, random, malloc

i'm trying to **generate pseudo-random numbers** with Park&Miller RNG ran0 1 2 3(3 doesn't work for the moment) in C++ from *"Numerical Recipes in C"*.
Theses generators work correctly because it makes samples uniformaly distributed between 0 and 1. 
My goal is to have a huge sample (10^10 at least) so i used malloc() function to allocate memory.
My problem is that the sample is always to small (i'd like to have "j" random numbers generated, for example: if i initialize **j=1000 i'll have 514 random numbers instead of 1000**, in order to test things i made different "for" loops).
I'm a total beginner in C++ (and in programming) and i fear a pointer problem, but i do not understand how to fix it. If someone has a solution or just a advice it would help me a lot because this problem seriously curb me in my internship (please be lenient with my approximative english :')). Here's the code:

```
int main(){
FILE* simulationr0 = fopen("E:/Simulation_stage/SimulationRan0","w");
FILE* simulationr1 = fopen("E:/Simulation_stage/SimulationRan1","w");
FILE* simulationr2 = fopen("E:/Simulation_stage/SimulationRan2","w");
FILE* simulationr3 = fopen("E:/Simulation_stage/SimulationRan3","w");
float d;
long j;
long seed;
printf("tapez 0 pour utiliser ran0\ntapez 1 pour utiliser ran1\ntapez 2 pour utiliser ran2\ntapez 3 pour utiliser ran3\ntapez 4 pour les utiliser tous");
scanf("%f",&d);
if( d!=0 & d!=1 & d!= 2 & d!= 3 & d!=4){
    printf("Erreur: valeur incorrecte//incorrect value\n");
    exit(0);}
printf("Combien de nombres pseudo-aleatoires ?// How many random numbers ?\n");
scanf("%lo",&j);
printf("Quelle graine ? Which seed ?\n");
scanf("%lo", &seed);
long *pseed=&seed;
if(d==4){
    float * ranp0;
    float * ranp1;
    float * ranp2;
    float * ranp3;
    ranp0 = (float*) malloc (j*sizeof(float));
    ranp1 = (float*) malloc (j*sizeof(float));
    ranp2 = (float*) malloc (j*sizeof(float));
    ranp3 = (float*) malloc (j*sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0;i<j+2;i+=1){
        ranp0[i]=ran0(pseed);
        ranp1[i]=ran1(pseed);
        ranp2[i]=ran2(pseed);
        ranp3[i]=ran3(pseed);
        fprintf(simulationr0,"%f\n", ranp0[i]);
        fprintf(simulationr1,"%f\n", ranp1[i]);
        fprintf(simulationr2,"%f\n", ranp2[i]);
        fprintf(simulationr3,"%f\n", ranp3[i]);
    }
    fclose(simulationr0);
    fclose(simulationr1);
    fclose(simulationr2);
    fclose(simulationr3);
    system("PAUSE");
    free(ranp0);
    free(ranp1);
    free(ranp2);
    free(ranp3);}
if(d==0){
    float * ranp0;
    ranp0 = (float*) malloc (j*sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0;i<j+2;i++){
        ranp0[i]=ran0(pseed);
        fprintf(simulationr0,"%f\n", ranp0[i]);}
    fclose(simulationr0);
    system("PAUSE");
    free(ranp0);}
if(d==1){
    float * ranp1;
    ranp1 = (float*) malloc (j*sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0;i<j+2;i++){
        ranp1[i]=ran1(pseed);
        fprintf(simulationr1,"%f\n", ranp1[i]);}
    fclose(simulationr1);
    system("PAUSE");
    free(ranp1);}
if(d==2){
    float * ranp2;
    ranp2 = (float*) malloc(j*sizeof(long));
    for (int i=0;i!=j;i=i+1){
        ranp2[i]=ran2(pseed);
        fprintf(simulationr2,"%f\n", ranp2[i]);}
    fclose(simulationr2);
    system("PAUSE");
    free(ranp2);}
if(d==3){
    float * ranp3;
    ranp3 = (float*) malloc(j*sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0;i<j+2;i++){
        ranp3[i]=ran3(pseed);
        fprintf(simulationr3,"%f\n", ranp3[i]);}
    fclose(simulationr3);
    system("PAUSE");
    free(ranp3);}
system("PAUSE");
exit(1);}
```

Comment: That's c and not c++.

Comment: octal 1000 == decimal 512, and you're reading numbers as octal.

Comment: `I'm a total beginner in C++` From what I can see in your question, what little you learned is C not C++.

Comment: You don't need any dynamic memory allocation as you only use 1 element at a time and free the memory afterwards. You could well do with a simple `float` variable instead of those arrays. Also your loops go beyond the end of your memory: `(int i=0;i<j+2;i+=1)` should be `(int i=0; i<j; i+=1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%lo",&j);
```

This interprets the number you enter as an octal integer, that is a number with only the digits 0 to 7.

Replace the o from the pattern with u.

```
scanf("%lu",&j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your format specifiers.  The specifier "%lo" tells `scanf` to read a string representation of an unsigned octal integer and store it in the `long` object pointed to by the corresponding argument.

That means when you input "1000", its interpreted as octal, and 1000<sub>8</sub> is the same as 512<sub>10</sub>.  You then add 2 to that number, which explains why you see 514 iterations for the input "1000".

Use "d" instead of "o" in your format specifiers to indicate a decimal integer:

```
scanf("%ld", &j);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it was exactly that ! I didn't notice that "lo" was for "Long Octal". It works perfectly